# MySQL Workbench appears to be caching a table upon Forward Engineer SQL Script

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL Workbench to design/build a schema for a database. I was all done with it and when I went to do my Forward Engineer SQL Script, one of the tables is a much older version. I changed all the names slightly (removing or adding one letter) to see if that would improve it. I run Forward Engineer SQL Script again, checking all 5 tables, and I get an export script with 6 tables on it. 5 with the correct columns and names, and one extra "ghost" table with the old name and old column names before I made changes to it.

Does anyone have any suggestions to solve this issue?

-- edit --

I tried saving and quitting. I tried restarting my machine. Did not fix the issue, this ghost table is starting to haunt me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that when I went to delete the old copy of the table, I accidentally clicked "Remove Figure" instead of "Delete".

This removed the image of the table on the grid, but the table was still declared and still very much alive. On the left, below 'Navigator' under the tab "Catalogue" I was able to find the list of all the tables. I dragged the table back to the main grid, then deleted it properly.

Feels like I successfully banished a ghost, but I'll leave these instructions here in case anyone else runs into the same issue that I did.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just delete the table on the model overview page, which will also tell you that the figure will be removed as well then.

Comment: Ghehe, I hd exactly the same thing and I couldn't let it go. Used just your method, thanks.